# What are these classified as?

Tags: single-word-requests

What are these classified as -- greed, hatred, pride, thinking oneself above others -- I don't want to call them emotions. I had originally thought of calling them virtues, emotions, conventions, desires... but I see that none of these work. Now I need a single word. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe they’re *character traits*

Comment: perhaps something with more "feeling". I'm going to be presenting my work to an audience, so I need a blend between academic and understandable language. But if worse comes to worst, this is a good option, thanks.

Comment: loads of people call them 'sins'

Comment: The ones you've listed are all **vices**. More generally, they're [ingrained] **attitudes**.

Comment: @Cascabel - Yeah I was gonna post *flaws* but decided to stay neutral since all of OP’s words are relatively neutral.

Comment: tenets of egocentrism

Comment: Flavors of self-centeredness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **[temperament](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/temperament)**
>
> ***1.The combination of mental, physical, and emotional traits of a person; natural predisposition.***
>
> ***2.Unusual personal attitude or nature as manifested by peculiarities of feeling, temper, action, etc., often with a
>   disinclination to submit to conventional rules or restraints.***

**[mindset](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mindset)** (noun)

***A habitual or characteristic mental attitude that determines how you will interpret and respond to situations.***

Comment: I need something that can be used like -- "These _traits_ are what drive humans to do this and that...." It seems a bit off to say -- these dispositions... especially in written form. But this is also another good option, thanks.

Comment: Perhaps 'mindset' or 'temperament'!

Comment: I think I can use mindset and temperament. Post them as answers and I will approve them.

Comment: @KidusAmare - You can also acknowledge the answerer's efforts by upvoting the answer.  Just click on the up arrow to the left of the answer. // *Mindset* is a good idea.

Comment: @aparente001, Thank you. This is really encouraging!